# How to serial objects into IMemoryCache

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-core, serialization

I have a .NET Core 5 website with a large product catalog.

Since it takes a long time to pull the whole catalog from the database (its a complex query), I load it once every 3 hours and put it in IMemoryCache as JSON.

```
public Catalog GetCatalog (IMemoryCache cache)
{
   string modelStr = cache.Get<Catalog>("catalogKey");
   if (model == null)
   { 
      catalog Model = loadCatalogData();
      modelStr =  JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
      cache.Set("catalogKey", modelStr, TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
   }
   else
   {
      Catalog model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Catalog>(modelStr);
   }
   return model;
}
```

(This is inside a lock to synchronize it, so that 2 users don't try to load the data at the same time.)

So before I add it to cache, I serialize the object to JSON and put the JSON in the cache.
Its about 2mb of text.
Then I have a GET method that deserializes it and serves it to the page.
I do this so that every user gets a different instance of it, and can't affect each others catalog with changes.

The problem is, when the load starts to reach around 400 concurrent users, I start getting Out Of Memory exceptions on the Deserialize function.

This happens with both NewtonSoft and System.Text.Json

In my latest attempt, I began using a memory stream as part of the deserialize, but it still runs out of memory.

It does not need to be JSON, but it does need to be a different instance that comes out for every user.

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: I would try storing in the cache a `Catalog` object. The `Catalog` object can have a copy/clone method to provide independent instances.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what we try, I think it is better to try to use a cache server, such as Redis.

In the application, it is certain to encounter insufficient memory when operating on IMemoryCache.